# What is service "ismserver" listening on port 9500?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port, nmap

I am on Ubuntu 16.04

Upon `nmap -sV localhost`, I came upon the output line `9500/tcp filtered ismserver` which I cannot recognize.

The service `ismserver` listening on the port matches the IANA record, as seen on 
http://www.adminsub.net/tcp-udp-port-finder/ismserver

That `nmap` reports the port as `filtered` probably also reflects the fact that I have denied incoming traffic on that port.

Yet, I am interested in what exactly is the service listening on the port, what it is doing, and how to disable it if possible.

May I ask if anyone might have some ideas?

Thanks heaps!

PS

1. `locate ismserver` returns no result.
2. Found something with similar name, but unsure if relevant: http://www.netplex-tech.com/docs/netvigil/v3.6/NetVigil%20Manual%20v3.6-19-1.html

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is listening on that port. Nmap marks the port as [`filtered`](https://secwiki.org/w/FAQ_filtered) when it gets no response. This usually doesn't happen for localhost scans, but I suppose something could have been missed. The "ismserver" service name is retrieved from a services database lookup and has no relevance to any running service, because the state of the port is not `open`.